# Displaying battery percentage with arduino

Tags: arduino, robotics

I would like to know if there is any way to display the battery level of an arduino running off a rechargeable battery. Is there some piece of equipment or certain code I could use with an LCD? To be clear I'm looking to display the battery percentage not the voltage.

I'm using an adafruit proto board with a servo shield

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for a display or for a battery meter?

Comment: I think that precisely monitoryng the battery level is really complicated. And this highly depends on the battery chemistry (Li-ION, LiPo, Lead Acid, ...). If you have to precisely monitor it, search for an IC which already does this for you and buy it. Probably you won't find any breakout board, so you'll have to design a small PCB yourself. If, on the other hand, you want just a rough "indication", then you can try to search for a discharge curve for your battery (e.g. [this one](http://www.rcuniverse.com/magazine/reviews/1183/AMPD14_DischargeCurve.jpg)), then sense your battery voltage and

Comment: then convert the voltage to the percentage according to the graph. Or, better, draw that graph yourself by discharging the battery at a constant current and periodically sensing the voltage. In any case, once you have the percentage you can display it on any display using standard libraries

Comment: I think you should better ask this question somewhere else, because this forum is not for hardware related questions..

Comment: @frankenapps in fact this can also be just implemented in software by sensing the voltage (read my previous comments)...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are avoiding the simple solution (resistor bridge into an analog input).  Create a map in EEPROM to act as an interpolation table and re-scale it occasionally.  Taking the voltage from that analog input and mapping it through your interpolation table will give you a percentage battery remaining for the LCD.  (most batteries I have interacted with slowly decrease in output voltage as their percentage remaining drops and the slope/ curve is usually fairly repeatable)